# Join if not exists

Tags: oracle, join, subquery, exists

I encountered following problem:

I have a long query (let's call it query "Z" ) that includes lots of joins and subqueries. It ouputs two columns:

- A: item
- B: Integer attribute, range guaranteed to be 1-10

I want to join from table X items (column A) that are not present as output of query Z and give them an arbitrary attribute value 10 (column B).

I tried creating subquery with inner subquery uisng not exists but that requires copying my original query inside and takes a lot of time (I didn't even manage to execute it).

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: So you basically want to end up with a table that contains all your results from query "Z" and additionally all items (from where?) that are not in "Z" with the second column as value "10"? Is the integer attribute limited to 10 ? Do all items that are present in "Z" have a value <=10?

Comment: Is your DBMS Oracle or MySQL ?

Comment: 1) yes i want to end up with table containing results from query Z with calculated attributes  in the query and additionally all items from table X with second column value 10. 2) Integer is limited to 10, yes all items present in "Z" have value <=10

Comment: database Oracle

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please act on [mcve] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & show what you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments , one possibility is to first make a `union` of the results of your "Z" query and then another `select` with the addition of only selecting the `MIN()` of your column B.
So it would look something along the lines of :

```
SELECT A , MIN(B) FROM
(
  (QUERY Z) AS Z 
  union
  (SELECT ITEM as A, 10 as B FROM X)
)
GROUP BY A
```

Comment: A nice trick. Just not as straight-forward as APC's query and probably much slower.

Comment: Have to agree with that. But I somehow have never heard of coalesce before. Always nice to learn new things.

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear from your question but I think you mean table `X` is a superset of the records from query `Z`. If so, a simple outer join should give you the result you want:

```
select coalesce(z.a, x.a) as a
       , coalesce(z.b, 10) as b
from x
     left outer join ( your query ) z
     on z.a = x.a
```

If `X` is not a superset of `Z` then you should try a FULL OUTER JOIN instead.

---

I have assumed that column `A` works as a UID for the query `Z` and the table `X`. If this is not the case you'll need to tweak the above statement, or edit your question to include more details.

Comment: Looks fine to me. `coalesce(z.a, x.a) as a` can be shortened to `x.a`, though.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - yes, you're right. I was hovering between `left outer` and `full outer` as the appropriate join. If it's `full outer` we need to coalesce both columns.

Answer (score 0):

I did it similarily to what @Ancaron posted.

```
SELECT A, B FROM Z
UNION ALL
SELECT A, '10' FROM X
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
select Z.A
from Z
WHERE Z.A=X.A
)
```

Comment: So you're still running the Z query twice? I thought that was what you were trying to avoid.